# Algorithm: Buffer effect on lines/other geometric shapes

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computational-geometry

**How to** generate **buffer** around **lines** or **any type of geometric shapes**?
Not interested in available packages such as [Shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/) etc but **wish to implement**.
[image]

Comment: Shapely is open source, so that'll tell you how to implement it. This is a big and complicated problem.

Comment: Here is SO, so this is to learn. Using always available package is not so good to learn. Getting algorithm from the source code is also so tricky sometime impossible. If somebody does not know the answer it is good to stay calm and learn. Down voting for such a simple and constructive question is not what you spend your time reading SO!

Comment: +1 To me it is interesting topic to learn too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited:**
This can be seen an indirect solution. If you can have your geometric shapes as image i.e., 2D matrix then you may implement (see below) simple functions such as dilation/erosion (fairly simple kernel jobs) etc to make surrounding areas around all the shapes (now pixels) on your image.

This is so straightforward than doing hard mathematics. The following shows an experiment.
The algorithm is simple:

1. shift-four-direction your matrix each time one pixel and repeat until you get desired 
   depth for the buffer.
2. sum resulting matrices

**That is it.**

*Apparently, for fancy output you may use contour or other function to generate lines from your output.*

[image]

**Update:**
Note that as mentioned this idea is so simple and actually is based on matrix demonstration of polygon, line or whatever is in the question. That is the resolution is defined by the dimensions of the representing matrix. One advantage is however it works with any complexity of the input.

The corners are seen to be descretized form of circle.

[image]

Comment: The asker specifically said they don't want an existing procedure, they want to know how to implement it for themselves.

Comment: @NickBarnes In my answer there is **no reference** to other package. If you concern about 'contour' function it can be eliminted if it is not necessary. That is, after doing simple kernel multiplications on the source 2D matrix you may have dialated/eroded output according to your request. That is simple as it is. I added a demonstration figure.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but you said `you may use image processing low-level procedures such as dilation/erosion`. Which sounds like you're suggesting an existing procedure. The question is how you would *write* that procedure.

Comment: +1 Looks promising. I will try to implement and have experiments see what happens.

Comment: @NickBarnes I got your point and so removed that misleading sentence avoiding misunderstanding. The dialation I meant and implemented is so simple as described now in the answer. It is just shitfing around the matrix one and so.

Comment: Could you repeat the example, with the entire dilated region in view? If I'm understanding your algorithm, I don't think that's going to give you round corners / endpoints (but we can't see any of them).

Comment: @NickBarnes I added one more example.

Comment: Thanks. The square corners don't quite fit with the asker's diagram, but it might be good enough for some applications.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically, this operation is a [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_sum). You should find a reference and some pseudo-code in a good book on compuational geometry. Try [Computational Geometry in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521649765) by O'Rourke, or [Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642096816) by Berg et al.

Comment: If you have access to those, could you provide some pesudo-code or even share with us how to implement Minkowski sum.

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution to dilation.

Use bresenham's line drawing algo.

```
for each pixel <p> along the line.
check surrounding pixels and fill all pixels <p'> that have that have distance(p,p') < radius <r>.
```

radius r is a prefined radius of a circle that you whish to use.